# Generate dynamic 'Span' controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, uiviewcontroller, runatserver

I am trying to create a  dynamic `span` controller ,because i need to insert my `Drop down list` that are created by code on it.

Here in page load i am creating a list of `DDl` as you can see here :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfQuestion; i++)
            {
                DropDownList ansList = new DropDownList();
                ansList.DataSource = clsVoAnswer.Answer;
                ansList.DataBind();
                ansList.AutoPostBack = true;
                ddll.Add(ansList);
            }
```

In my page i create a `span` tag that runs in server as you can see here :

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfQuestion; i++)
    {
        Response .Write("<div class='rows-score' style='background:transparent'>"+
                           "<div class='columns-score'> " +
                                "<span>" +
                                        listQuestion[i].Question +
                                "</span>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='columns-score' style='float:left'>" +
                                "<span style='color:#ea0000;padding:0 10px;' id='Span"+i.ToString()+"' runat='server'></span>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>");
        Span[i].Controls.Add(ddll[i]);
    }
```

So i need to put my `DDl` on `Span` tag.But my code can't access the `Span` tag ,it is clear why i can't access .

In my previous project i add `span` tag manually and i can use this code :

```
Span1.Controls.Add(ddll[0]);
```

But here i generate the `span` tag using `for` .I want to access the `span` in my code that is created dynamically by `for`.

Any idea .

Best regards